# Removing an icon on the taskbar (the one on the right of the application launcher) - the screenshot should explain what I mean

Tags: kubuntu, kde, panel, taskbar

**Update**
Thanks to good people on #kde here is the solution:

Right click on the bottom right in the taskbar, then "panel settings", then  right click on the icon we want to get rid of and finally "remove icon".

**Original question**

On this screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kaxO.jpg on the bottom (taskbar) right to the "application launcher" icon, there is another icon - chrome. I did it by mistake. On taskmanager -> right click ->  Task manager settings -> sorting I selected "manually" - and, I wanted to drag a chrome app (a button on the taskbar) to the most left.

But it seems I moved too far to the left, and an icon was created. I don't want this icon. When I right-click on it, I can only see "remove this panel" but AFAIK this will remove the entire taskbar. How can I remove this icon?

Or, maybe this will help me - where does KDE store its config about what is in the application launcher, taskbar etc?

Comment: I hope, this article would help you: [How do I remove launchers from the KDE panel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215015/how-do-i-remove-launchers-from-the-kde-panel/215016)

Comment: Thanks! I don't have enough points to plus it :(